# How to reduce width of ComboBox's dropdown arrow in wpf?

Tags: wpf, drop-down-menu, controltemplate

I have a wpf/mvvm application. I have a combobox (drop down) in that. I would like to reduce the width of the drop down arrow...

I know that I can replace the template...but how do I build an arrow mark ?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the standard [`ComboBox` control templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx), you will see a [`System.Windows.Shapes.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.aspx) used to create the arrow. See below for partial capture of the `ComboBoxToggleButton`...

```
 <Path 
    x:Name="Arrow"
    Grid.Column="1"     
    Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
```

You would have to alter the [`Data` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.data.aspx) to change the geometric path drawn to create the arrow in the control template.

Comment: Is the toggle button represent the arrow in dropdown ?

Comment: Yes the WPF combobox is itself entirely a togglebutton **templated** to only display that arrow part of it as the actual button.